# Is there a way to lock/unlock iOS 14 widgets?

Tags: ios

So I want to offer the widget only for paid(IAP) subscribers. Is there a way to lock the widget and unlock if once user has paid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widgets are made as separate target and their configuration is independent from user purchase state.

However you can configure how widgets will appear, based on user subscription state and for example disable their content, informing user that he has to be premium to see it's content.

I think it also makes more  sense to alter content for widgets instead of hiding it from widgets library - to handle case when user subscription has expired, but user added it already to his screen.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you